# machine learning - multi label classification svm

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, svm

I'm having trouble in using **SVM** in multi-class classification in Python.
I fact, the problem is about gender classification (from images) where **training** dataset contains only either "**y=1**" **or** "**y=-1**" as class labels (binary). But, in **prediction**, I have to predict "**1**" if it is male or "**-1**" if it female and **"0" if classifier doesn't know**. I have no idea how to add this "0" class. What should I use? decision_function?

PS: score is calculated this way: [score_formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksxSs.png)

Comment: Can you please provide the code you have already? Best would be together with a minimal dataset containing 5 instances or so

Comment: It's an interesting question that may exceed the domain of stackoverflow and it's not a "technique" problem. Maybe http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is better. For example, you have to decide the punishment of the decision of "0", or else everyone can predict everything as 0.

Comment: Since you have your custom score, why not use neural network and make your "score" become the loss function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve the desired result would be to use probability. If you use `Scikit-learn` you can add the parameter `probability=True` to the constructor. That way you get a value between `[0,1]`.
An alternative is to use the `decision_function` which provides you the distance to the hyperplane. This should be `-1` and `1` for the support vectors. The absolute value is larger `1` if it is save classification. It is up to you where you choose 0.

Comment: means using decision function, I can predict 1 if >1, -1 if < -1, and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Yes. If the classes are separable this would even be justifiable. As it would imply that the examples in [-1,1] are closer to the decision boundary than anything seen before.